# Orchard - Set special Media folder

Tags: orchardcms, jplayer

I need to setup the jPlayer directory to a folder which is not called "/Default/MediaGallery" but "/MyFolder/CurrentMedia/".

Please, can anyone help me to find a way to change the setting in jPlayer - Version: 1.0.1

Regards

Comment: wow, that's an old version of jPlayer...

Comment: I have no updates in Orchard visible for jPlayer. If I upgrade Orchard CMS itselfes to one minor version higher, some other stuff does not work like navigation. I hope you can answer in any way to my question?

Comment: well, there is no such option to set a "Media Gallery Folder" in jPlayer.. this is purely an Orchard issue.. sorry i cannot help you with Orchard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the name [is hardcoded](http://orchardjplayer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74a5b8e71fb3#Services/MediaGalleryService.cs). There is no way to get rid of the *"/Default"* part of the path, as the jPlayer module is using the Orchard Media feature, which has a default root folder named after each of the tenants (it's a multitenant-friendly module).
You can alter only the following part of that path by changing the name (*MediaGalleries*) in line 12 of the file linked above.

Answer (score 1):

@PiotrSzmyd is right, it's partly hardcoded. The "Default" comes from the field `Name` in `Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt` and the paths are hardcoded in `Orchard\FileSystems\Media\FileSystemStorageProvider.cs`. Sadly there is no way to change the behaviour of this class with handlers or something. There are 2 options now

1. change the source code of Orchard
2. work around it by adding a module that provides a custom implementation of `IStorageProvider` and when needed (means media storage path is outside of the Orchard directory structure) an additional MVC controller to serve the media files.

I changed the media storage path to `\\<server>\Files$\<build_configuration>\Media` by using the second option.

First, here's the essential parts of the `IStorageProvider`:

**Custom `IStorageProvider` implementation**

```
[Orchard.Environment.Extensions.OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.FileSystems.Media.FileSystemStorageProvider")] // adopted from AzureBlobStorageProvider.cs
public class FileSystemStorageProvider : Orchard.FileSystems.Media.IStorageProvider
{
  private Orchard.FileSystems.Media.FileSystemStorageProvider mFileSystemStorageProvider;

  public FileSystemStorageProvider(Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettings settings)
  {
    // use Orchard's default IStorageProvider for implementation
    mFileSystemStorageProvider = new Orchard.FileSystems.Media.FileSystemStorageProvider(settings);

    var lFileSystemStorageProviderType = mFileSystemStorageProvider.GetType();

    // get media storage path, e.g. from configuration file
    var lStoragePath = GetMediaStoragePath();

    lStoragePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(lStoragePath, settings.Name);

    // _storagePath is private read-only, so change it the hard way by using reflection
    lFileSystemStorageProviderType
      .GetField("_storagePath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .SetValue(mFileSystemStorageProvider, lStoragePath);

    string lVirtualPath = "~/Files/" + settings.Name + "/";

    lFileSystemStorageProviderType
      .GetField("_virtualPath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .SetValue(mFileSystemStorageProvider, lVirtualPath);

    string lPublicPath = mFileSystemStorageProvider.GetPublicUrl(null).Replace("/Media/" + settings.Name + "/", "/Files/" + settings.Name + "/");

    lFileSystemStorageProviderType
      .GetField("_publicPath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .SetValue(mFileSystemStorageProvider, lPublicPath);
  }

  #region Implementation of IStorageProvider

    public bool FileExists(string aPath)
    {
      return mFileSystemStorageProvider.FileExists(aPath);
    } 
    ...

  #endregion
}
```

This custom implementation maps

- storage path to `\\<server>\Files$\<build_configuration>\Media`
- virtual path to `~/Files/Default/`
- absolute path to `/Files/Default/`

There is a problem now. Orchard would render media URLs as `www.mysite.de/Files/Default...` but there is no directory called Files in the Orchard directory structure. Now the custom route comes into play.

**Custom route**

```
public class Routes : Orchard.Mvc.Routes.IRouteProvider
{
  public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
  {
    Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor[] lRoutes =
      new Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor[] 
      {
        new Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor()
        {
          Name = "Custom route for media files",
          Priority = 10000, 
          Route = new System.Web.Routing.Route(
            "Files/{*aRelativePath}",
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() 
            { 
              {"area", "MyModule"},
              {"controller", "Media"},
              {"action", "GetFile"}
            }, 
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() {},
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { {"area", "MyModule"} },
            new System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler()
          )
        }
      };

    return lRoutes;
  }

  public void GetRoutes(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor> arRoutes)
  {
    foreach (var lRouteDescriptor in GetRoutes())
      arRoutes.Add(lRouteDescriptor);
  }
}
```

This route implementation ensures a redirect of `www.mysite.de/Files/Default...` to a specific media controller that looks like this:

**Media controller**

```
public class MediaController
{
  public MediaController(Orchard.FileSystems.Media.IMimeTypeProvider aMimeTypeProvider)
  {
    mMimeTypeProvider = aMimeTypeProvider;
  }

  public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetFile(string aRelativePath)
  {
    string lMediaStoragePath, lErrorMessage;

    // get media storage path, e.g. from configuration file
    if (GetMediaStoragePath(out lMediaStoragePath, out lErrorMessage))
    {
      string lFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(lMediaStoragePath, aRelativePath);
      string lMimeType = mMimeTypeProvider.GetMimeType(lFilename);

      return File(lFilename, lMimeType);
    }
    else
      return Content(lErrorMessage);
  }

  // private
    private Orchard.FileSystems.Media.IMimeTypeProvider mMimeTypeProvider;
}
```